# Glowing Mesh (topology)

Tags: mesh, materials, shader-nodes

Anyone knows how to create this glowing mesh effect?

[image: Glowing mesh couch]

Video link: https://youtu.be/dKo0rWXVAlc?t=18

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, add a wireframe modifier, uncheck "replace original", material offset 1, and add a blue color (i assume you already have a material) with lots of emission and if you render in eevee: turn bloom on.

emission 50:

[image]

emission 200:

[image]